# Hibernate OneToOne mapping executes select statement before insert; not sure why

Tags: hibernate

I configured a simple OneToOne mapping in my entity, but when I persist the object I see a "Select" statement being executed by Hibernate just before the Insert and I don't know why.

```
@Entity 
@Table( name = "USER" )
public class NewUser {

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="user_status_type_id", nullable=false)
   private UserStatusType userStatusType;
```

UserStatusType is just a read-only lookup table, so nothing persists in that table when I save User.

```
User u = new User();
u.setUserStatusType( new UserStatusType(101));
session.persis(u);
```

But when I persist the User object, the output from Hibernate reads as follows:

```
Hibernate: select userstatus_.user_status_type_id, userstatus_.user_status_name as user2_3_ from USER_STATUS_TYPE userstatus_ where userstatus_.user_status_type_id=?
Hibernate: insert into USER (created, first_name, last_name, password, user_name, user_status_type_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I don't know if that's normal for Hibernate. I figured since it was a "persist" operation I would only see an Insert statement; not sure of the purpose for the Select.

Is the mapping incorrect?

Comment: How do you persist and which object is referenced by `userStatusType` when persisting?

Comment: I updated the original post with more details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I was able to get an answer from the Hibernate forums. To prevent the `SELECT` before `INSERT`, if you are sure the referenced row exists in the database, then use `Session.load()` or `EntityManager.getReference()`.

```
User u = new User();
u.setUserStatusType( session.load(UserStatusType.class, new Long(id));
session.persist(u);
```

The `session.load()` method doesn't initially load anything, it just creates a proxy for the object and avoids a hit to the database. Now, if you want to access a member (other than the id field) from the class within the context of the session, then Hibernate will go to the database. In my case I just needed the primary key from the referenced object for the `INSERT`, so I avoided the database hit.

Comment: @user646584 nice research! You can accept your own answer by clicking the tick-box.

Comment: Can we explain the reason of this behavior (select before insert)?

Comment: I had used session.load but it's throwing ConstraintViolationException. in your case it's throwing for UserStatusType field..

Comment: This is why I prefer plain ol' jdbc - clear as day and easy to maintain. Hibernate obscures the developer's intention and creates more problems than it solves.