# Force Hibernate Insert Without Select Statements

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jboss, persistence

I am attempting to insert a new record into a table that I know is unique before hand. I have tried calling save() on the object, but that does a bunch of SELECT statements before doing any INSERTs, which I don't want to do because I know the object is already unique.

I am opening a new session for each transaction, which I can see being an issue, but that is a constraint of my domain. Is there some way to force Hibernate to not do any SELECTs before it INSERTs?

Comment: what SELECT statements does hibernate generate?

Comment: it generates a SELECT for each object in my domain, which I don't want to do because I already know my objects are completely new and unique.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the persist() method rather than save().

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1011405

However, unlike save(), persist() does not guarantee that the identifier value will be set immediately on the persisted instance.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=951275

(and you can jump to christian's last post in the thread)

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate is trying to determine if the object is transient or not, so is performing a `SELECT` before `INSERT`. You might be able to adapt this answer from [Hibernate OneToOne mapping executes select statement before insert; not sure why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208334/hibernate-onetoone-mapping-executes-select-statement-before-insert-not-sure-why/5280956#5280956) to avoid the `SELECT`.

Or, I remember a post in a forum about overriding the `version` column that hibernate uses in the transient check (and for optimistic locking). I'll edit this answer when I find it.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit Persistable and override isNew as following:

```
public class MyEntity implements Persistable<KeyType> {
  @Id
  private KeyType id;

  @Transient
  private boolean isNew = false;  // this tells next `save()` usually to do `UPDATE to DB`

  public KeyType getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public boolean isNew() {
    return isNew;
  }

  // constructor when you create new Entity assigning 100% new unique id:
  public MyEntity(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.isNew = true;  // this tells next `save()` to do `INSERT INTO DB`
    ...
  }
  
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't issue a select to see if an object is unique upon a `save()`. In point of fact, Hibernate doesn't even issue an insert when you call `save()`. That happens when you `flush()` or commit the transaction. You'll need to find out exactly what the selects are for and what's initiating them. To help narrow it down, you could write a quick test like

```
Session session = openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(myObject);
tx.commit();
```

and see what statements that produces.